# SQL Update or Insert

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, sqlite3

Уважаемые форумчане! Требуется ваша помощь!

Подскажите, как правильно? Задача простая, нужно **записать визит пользователя в базу данных**.

- **Подключаемся** к базе данных.
- **Обновляем** запись о посетителе в таблице.
- А вдруг посетитель впервые и его записи нет, значит **вставляем** запись.
- Для развёртывания (для первого запуска): А вдруг таблицы нет, значит **создаём** таблицу.

**Вопрос 1:** Беспокоит то, что каждый раз при обновлении (update) куча холостых операций (create, insert), может это как то иначе решается, подскажите.

**Вопрос 2:** А как вы решаете задачи которые требуются однократно при первом запуске?

**Вопрос 3:** Подключение к базе данных. Может в другой файл переместить? Но тогда при перемещении файла будут проблемы, а если оставить - то постоянно открывается и закрывается подключение к базе данных в разных файлах.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:file.sqlite');
  $db -> exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tableName' (
    id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    user TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    visitCounter INTEGER DEFAULT '0'
  )");
  $db -> exec("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO 'tableName' (user) VALUES ('user1')");
  $db -> exec("UPDATE 'tableName' SET visitCounter = visitCounter + 1 WHERE user = 'user1'");
unset($db);
```

Comment: Таблицу в БД можно создать заранее. Соединение с БД лучше делать в одном месте, а потом просто отдавать это соединение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1,2.** Вам придется их совершать потому что нужно проверить действительно ли есть уже эта запись. Я конечно не знаю архитектуру вашей системы. Но я бы лучше вместе с созданием пользователя добавлял его в нужные таблицы и тогда не нужно было бы каждый раз прописывать INSERT

**3.** Подключение к бд должно находится в отдельном файле и в том скрипте где вам потребуется работать с бд вы его подключаете с помощью `require()`

Comment: Вы правы, наверное моя проблема возникает потому что некоторые пользователи уже есть, а некоторые добавятся позже